# Why isn't it accepting any of my Nick name?

Tags: pokemon-go

I have caught my first Pokemon and now it is asking me for a nickname so when I type any Nick name it tells it isn't available. For every name I type it shows the same. Why is it so..... Why don't u tell which available and which to keep...

Comment: yes, try some unique nick name so it will be added easily

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can't use names that already were used by someone else. Due to so many people playing Pokémon Go, almost every name is already taken.

I know it looks ugly, but you should try to use names with 'modified' letters and numbers. Example: Instead of 'Player', try 'Pláy3r'.

Comment: ultimate one: XxPl4y3rxX

Comment: @Momo p. I know that is intended as a joke, but as a side fact, the xx surrounding your name used to signalize that you are a hacked back in the day.

Comment: really? That was absolutely not my intention. Well, it's true that it doesn't really sounds like a Pokemon Trainer nickname...

Comment: In case anyone wants to know more details, [here](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090712215454AAPtWGC) is a link to someone extensively explaining it.